# Is there any difference between returning a void vs returning a CompletionStage<Void>?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

More specifically, what are the differences, is any, in these two pieces of code, one returning `void` and other returning `CompletionStage<Void>`?

- What advantages of using one of `void` or `CompletionStage<Void>` over the other?
- In CODE SAMPLE 2, I'm not making use of the variable `x` in `thenCompose`. Is there a better way of writing it?
- Is it a better practice if I return a `boolean` in the function `doValidation` and check if `true` in `performTask` function?

**CODE SAMPLE 1:**

```
public CompletionStage<Response> performTask(Request request) throws MyException {
    doValidation(request);
    return service.performTask(request).thenCompose(serviceResponse -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(buildMyResponse(serviceResponse)));
}

private void doValidation(Request request) throws MyException {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // Validate
        if (*someCondition*) {
            throw new MyException(.....);
        }
    });
}
```

**CODE SAMPLE 2:**

```
public CompletionStage<Response> performTask(Request request) throws MyException {
    return doValidation(request).thenCompose(x -> {
        return service.performTask(request).thenCompose(serviceResponse -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(buildMyResponse(serviceResponse)));
    });
}

private CompletionStage<Void> doValidation(Request request) throws MyException {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // Validate
        if (*someCondition*) {
            throw new MyException(.....);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe in sample one, as validation is an async operation it may or may not happen by the time task is performed in service. However, in sample two the task gets performed after the stage is complete I.e., validation is performed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am addressing your first question

```
What advantages of using one of void or CompletionStage<Void> over the other?
```

To understand the difference, you should try logging the flow. It will help you identify how different they both work.

Here is an example similar to the approaches you followed. I came up with my own example because I don't know your code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tryWithVoid();
        //      tryWithCompletionStageVoid();
    }

    public static void tryWithVoid() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        validate(null);
        System.out.println("Exit");
    }

    public static void tryWithCompletionStageVoid() {
        System.out.println("Started");
        validateCS(null).thenRun(() -> System.out.println("Validation complete"));
        System.out.println("Exit");
    }

    public static CompletionStage<Void> validateCS(String val) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            if (val == null) {
                System.out.println("Validation failed! value is null");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void validate(String val) {
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            if (val == null) {
                System.out.println("Validation failed! value is null");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If you run `tryWithVoid()`, you will see that the output will be:

```
Started
Exit
Validation failed! value is null
```

Whereas, when you run `tryWithCompletionStageVoid()`, it will be:

```
Started
Validation failed! value is null
Validation complete
Exit
```

In first approach, `tryWithVoid()`, it is not waiting for the operation to complete. So the result of the operation may or may not be available for the code following the invocation.

However, in second approach `tryWithCompletionStageVoid()`, it waits for the stage to complete before running the next stage.

If you don't have dependency between the stages, you can go with `void`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that with returning a `void` you cannot do anything chained to the `CompletableFuture` after it finishes.

When you return `CompletableFuture<Void>` you can chain further things to it. For example invoke `thenRun()`, `thenRunAsync()`, or simply `join()` to wait for it to finish if needed.

So it depends on whether the caller cares about the status of the `CompletableFuture` and wants to apply further logic attached to it.

In your case, in Sample 1, `doValidation()` is running on a separate thread, and whatever happens to it is really irrelevant. `service.performTask()` will take place independently of it, and could even start and/or finish before `doValidation()`.

In Sample 2, `doValidation()` has to finish successfully before `performTask()` actually takes place. So it seems that this version is actually the correct one. Keep in mind that the *main* thread running `CompletionStage<Response> performTask()` will finish and return immediately after setting up the pipeline, the actual performValidation() could still be running (or could even not have been started yet).

By the way you can simplify the call as follows:

```
service.performTask(request).thenApply(this::buildMyResponse);
```

You don't have to wrap it in a `CompletableFuture` again just to unwrap it again with `thenCompose()`.

Comment: Okay, I now understand that in my first case, the service.performTask() may complete executing before doValidation(). I just want to clarify if a function can also 'return' a value before one of it's statements (here doValidation) completes executing? Basically, is there a distinction between executing and returning?

Comment: @KalyanM in this case yes, the function can return before `doValidation()` completes, or even before `doValidation()` even starts if there are other tasks in queue before it that need to finish before its turn comes. Similarly, you have no guarantee that `service.performTask()` has finished, or even started, when the outer `CompletionStage<Response> performTask()` returns. They are all potentially on separate threads.